# Double data type represented by int data type (low, high) struct in a union

Tags: c++

Is the following a valid representation?  I'm aware of byte order, this is a Windows environment.  If I define `Int32Double myVar`; will `myVar.int32.low` always be the same if `myVar.d` is a computed value?
E.G: `myVar.d = 0.4 * log(4); printf("%08X\n", myVar.int32.low);`

```
union Int32Double
{
    struct
    {
        int low;
        int high;
    } int32;

    double d;
};
```

Comment: That would be dependent on the format the floating point double was stored in. If it does work it may be highly dependent on the hardware you're on

Answer (score 3):

No, it's undefined behavior writing into `d` and reading from `int32`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the object representations of integral types and floating-point types are typically very different. Reinterpreting any part of `double` object as an `int` object will not usually produce any value that would resemble the original `double` value. The result will not be meaningful, unless you really know what you are doing. And if one does know what one's doing, one uses *unsigned* integral types for reinterpretation.

Secondly, using unions for memory reinterpretation is illegal in C++. It leads to undefined behavior. One of the latest technical corrigendums to C99 specification actually made it legal in C language (with implementation-defined behavior, of course, and as long as we don't attempt to access a trap representation). But AFAIK it is not in C++ yet. So, use at your own risk.

P.S. I'm not sure what you mean by your "will always be the same"...